# Regular expression. Select from one word to another

Tags: regex

I need to select text from `<BLOCK_START>` to `<BLOCK_END>`. How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
(?s)<BLOCK_START>.*?<BLOCK_END>
```

where `.*?` means "zero or more characters", the `?` stands for "as less as possible" and `(?s)` makes the `.` match also line breaks and carriage returns.

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/XON3Ae/1).